# How to tell Linux where initramfs is in RAM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, initramfs

I'm trying to boot a Linux kernel running on top of Xen with a initramfs copied into RAM by the bootloader.

In the device tree I took out a chunk of memory so the kernel will not overwrite the area I copy the initramfs to.

```
memory {
    device_type = "memory";
-    reg = <0x0 0x0 0x0 0x80000000 0x8 0x0 0x0 0x80000000>;
+    reg = <0x0 0x0 0x0 0x60000000 0x8 0x0 0x0 0x80000000>;
};
```

When in uboot, I copy the initramfs to `0x60000000` and a fitimage with the dom0 kernel, device tree, and xen image to `0x8000000` then boot.

My bootargs for dom0 are

```
xen,dom0-bootargs = "console=hvc0 earlycon=xen earlyprintk=xen rootdelay=1 root=/dev/ram0 rw rd_start=0x60000000 rd_size=0x114a3000 clk_ignore_unused";
```

I got the `rd_start` and `rd_size` bootargs from [here](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Kernel_Command_Line_Arguments) which was initially suggested from [this StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27309/how-do-i-have-linux-boot-with-a-rootfs-in-ram).

I'm questioning if I'm using an incorrect initramfs (ext4) because in the stack trace of the kernel panic, `mount_block_root()` is called and fails. However, before the panic it prints

```
No filesystem could mount root, tried: ext3 ext4 ext2 cramfs vfat msdos btrfs
```

Because of the lack of documentation on this I'm questioning if I'm going in the right direction here or if I'm way off.